# I'm trying to enhance the contrast of image using following code

Tags: python, image, numpy

Here i'm trying to:
     - Apply Adaptive filtering to image .
     - Enhance the contrast of image .
 my code is as follow :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFilter

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('Crop.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('original',img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)     

th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
     cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
cv2.imshow('image',th3)
th3 = th3.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
cv2.imshow('image',th3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting following Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "./adaptive.py", line 22, in
>
> th3 = th3.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'filter

Answer (score 0):

You may confuse with [cv.Smooth](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=.smooth#cv.Smooth)

Comment: If you are you satisfied with this answer, you can accept it.